# Получить номер массива найденной строки. C#

Tags: c#, массивы, строки

Короче, есть массив строк:

- Строка 0 `"CriticalProtect: 1"`
- Строка 1 `"Lol: 0"`
- Строка 2 `"SexNLol:2`

Эти строки все в массиве, как получить массив строки по поиску, к примеру:

Ищу строку `Lol` и получаю ее массив, и изменяю его, на `Lol: 1`.
У меня получается по массиву изменить строку, а как его получить? 
Строки могут быть любыми, т.е Строка 2, может быть и первой.

Код который сейчас есть:

```
(' string[] allText = File.ReadAllLines("Settings.cfg", Encoding.UTF8);
allText[12] = "FIRST_LOGIN : 1"; File.WriteAllLines("Settings.cfg", allText, Encoding.UTF8);)
```

Comment: "массив строки по поиску", "получаю ее массив", "по массиву изменить строку" - это на каком языке?

Comment: Мне надо найти строку в файле а затем получить ее номер массива. Либо [0] либо [1] либо [2].

Comment: Что такое "ее номер массива"? Индекс?

Comment: Да, индекс. Просто по привычке называю номером.

Comment: Код, пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Как код добавить в вопрос?

Comment: Ссылка "править" под вопросом. В редакторе вопроса кнопка "{}".

Comment: Вы можете помочь как получить индекс строки найдя ее по фразе?

Comment: Могу, конечно. Покажите, как Вы ищите строку, и Вам скажу, как определить ее индекс.

Comment: Строку ищу так: `string fileText = File.ReadAllText("Settings.yml");
                            if (fileText.Contains("First login to the program. = Allow"))`

Comment: А вам не кажется, что вы изобретаете велосипед? Для хранения настроек есть куча разных форматов, которые читаются/записываются элементарно. `JSON`, `XML` к примеру. Есть встроенный `ConfigurationManager`. Ну на крайний случай можно использовать старый добрый `ini`... P.S. если комент выше - текущий формат, то `.yml` тоже парсится довольно легко и без велосипедов...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не, нет, не так поняли, есть игра, и в ней есть конфиг файл, файл настроек игры, и там эти строки.))

Answer (score 0):

Вы всё хорошо делаете, теперь осталось провести поиск в цикле.

```
string[] allText = File.ReadAllLines("Settings.cfg", Encoding.UTF8);
int number = GetNumber(allText ,"Lol");

int GetNumber(string[] strings,string token) {
   for(int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++) {
      if(strings[i].Contains(token))
         return i;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: "GetNumber(string[], string)": не все ветви кода возвращают значение. Что не так делается?

Comment: @PavelErokhin поправил

Comment: А как изменить значение найденного массива? Допустим, с 0 на 1.

Comment: @PavelErokhin вам нужно понять значения понятий, вы нашли не массив, а индекс или номер элемента в массиве. Значения изменяются очевидно `allText[number] = value;` но в вашем случае вам нужно ещё вытащить ту часть что после ":" и уже туда записывать.

Comment: Нет, что-то делаю не так, или дико туплю, к сожалению не работает.

Comment: @PavelErokhin что именно не работает?

Comment: Не меняется значение и даже не читается походу. ~_~ Вот ведь не задача.

Comment: @PavelErokhin видимо вы просто скопировали... Тут так не проходит, нужно программировать понимая что происходит. Рекомендую не сразу делать рабочую задачу, а для начала поделать тестовые задачки, поупражняться, почитать руководства.